# Sticky elements disappear/flicker when scrolling on latest Android Chrome (85)

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a website that contains a header element with the following CSS:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 3;
```

In the latest Chrome on Android this element seems to disappear every time the user scrolls. It reappears when the scroll motion is done, which makes it look like the element is flickering on and off while scrolling through the page. When I simulate a Nexus 5X in desktop Chrome the same thing happens, but only when I use touch input to scroll. When I use the scroll wheel the header element stays visible the whole time. It also didn't seem to occur in older versions and it's also working fine on desktop Chrome and other browsers.

Has something recently changed about how Chrome handles `position: sticky` when scrolling? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Got a minimal demo that shows the issue?

Comment: 0

I've got a similar issue. It doesn't seem to be related to position: sticky; to me, but to an element that is transformed to a new position (not when scrolling, but just on load of the page).

I haven't got my example live but experienced the same thing on another site: https://hanstholm.com/ - I haven't made this site, but just noticed the flickering of the images when scrolling up and down in Chrome. The images are transformed as the elements I've experienced it on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same issue in Chrome on Android (v85.0.4183.81) when using `position: sticky`. It only seems to occur when the content is wider than the viewport and is being scaled down to fit it by the viewport meta tag.

I've created a minimal repro on CodePen but it needs to run full screen so will only show the issue on CodePen's debug mode which runs without the iframe: https://codepen.io/mavman/pen/ZEWxoab

Adding `minimum-scale=1` to the viewport meta tag seems to fix it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1">
```

This isn't an option for me as I need some content to be able to scale down to the size of the viewport so I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed by an update to v85.0.4183.101 this morning. Looks like it might have been this Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1110872

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, you can reproduce it using the desktop Chrome's devtools and a Galaxy S5 view with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta id="viewport" name=viewport content="width=320">
</head>

<body>

<div style="position: sticky; height:40px; top: 0px; background-color: #ff0000;">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div style="height: 10000px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A new Update as of this morning seems to fix the issue!